# Find the probability that two such proofreaders working independently will miss at least one error in a work that contains four errors.

Tags: probability

A professional proofreader has a 98% chance of detecting an error in a piece of written work (other than misspellings, double words, and similar errors that are machine detected). A work contains four errors. Find the probability that two such proofreaders working independently will miss at least one error in a work that contains four errors.

a) 0.0776
b) 0.9996
c) 0.0016
d) 0.9696

I tried P(all errors found)^2 and P(all errors)*2 but it is not in the given answers

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well, start from computing probability that at least one proofreader detects an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=2\%$ be the probability that one proofreader misses a particular error. The probability that this error is missed by both proofreaders then is $p^2$, and the probability that this error is detected then comes to $1-p^2$.

This allows to compute the probability that each of the four errors is detected, and finally the desired probability that at least one error remains undetected.